# Problems re-establishing wireless connection after messing with ndiswrapper/modules

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

My wireless connection speed only crawled, but when connected, very fast.  With the help of a community member, I thought I had it fixed by installing ndiswrapper, downloading .inf driver file (windows driver for my computer), and various other tweaks which I had no business attempting on my own after I thought it was fixed.  Long story short, I messed up and cannot find any networks, wireless seems gone altogether, and wlan0 does not appear.  On shutdown, I also notice a flash of firmware missing, or something like that.

Am not sure what all I should provide, so if any other pastes would be of help i will provide them.

http://pastebin.com/WLLF7FpE

Details: OS Ubuntu 13.10 Memory 5.3 GiB Processor AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO OS Type 64-bit Disk 732.5 GB

Comment: Does your wireless spring to life if you do, in a terminal: sudo modprobe ndiswrapper

Comment: no.  comes back with "FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found".

Comment: i tried to reverse some of the things i did and, thus, have made a mess so far beyond me

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall the ndiswrapper suite. From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 dkms
```

Now see if you can load the module:

```
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Check for informative messages:

```
dmesg | grep ndis
```

If the module still cannot be found, compile ndiswrapper from source. With a temporary wired ethernet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

If one or both are already installed, please proceed. Download this file to your desktop:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/files/stable/ndiswrapper-1.59.tar.gz/download Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.59
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Now is it working? Check:

```
ndiswrapper -l
iwconfig
```

Reload the Windows XP .inf file. Find out where it is; assuming it's in a folder on your desktop:

```
cd ~/Desktop/WindoowsDrivers  <--or wherever the original .inf is located
sudo ndiswrapper -i <some_file>.inf  <--or whatever the file is named
sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper && sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Check:

```
ndiswrapper -l
iwconfig
```

Please be sure that rt2800pci is not loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rt2
```

If it is loaded, unload it and blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800pci
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Is yours a 64-bit install?

```
arch
```

If so, you will have difficulty getting ndiswrapper to work at all and even if you do, you need an x64 .inf file. If you decide to reinstall, I will be happy to help you troubleshoot the native driver rt2800pci.

Comment: seemed to reinstall perfectly, but second cmd returned, "sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found."

Comment: Please check for informative messages as in my answer.

Comment: not sure if i am understanding, but the last cmd output is "brandt@Brandtsys:~$ dmesg | grep ndis
 brandt@Brandtsys:~$"        nothing.  do you mean for me to copy the output of first cmd?

Comment: Please do so; paste it here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: here is the link  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6729228/

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: no. the following link from output of edit:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6729417/

Comment: Is the folder on your desktop? Did you right-click and extract the tar.gz?

Comment: K, something happened. I am lost as to what: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6729522/

Comment: What happened is that ndiswrapper loaded as expected!! Please see my edit.

Comment: I don't know, but still not working.  Output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6729722/

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: The driver installed and said it had supporting hardware, but won't load.  Informative messages here:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6734447/

Comment: What does this tell us? arch

Comment: I don't know? I followed your edit exactly.  It still isn't working, nor showing any networks, or wireless signal.  I'm lost.  Sorry.  If I may just show last output in paste.  After this I guess I just need to do clean install if it can't be fixed.http://paste.ubuntu.com/6734802/

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: 2800pci not loaded. Arch X86_64.  On start up I saw something about Raedon not loading?  Could it be the RT3090? It's like I have no Wireless, Network, etc.  Are you of the opinion it would be best, at this point to do clean install?

Comment: Radeon is a video driver. We can troubleshoot for days or you can reinstall in 15 minutes. Let the native rt2800pci load and let's troubleshoot it from there.

Comment: Ok.  Sounds like best idea at this point.

Comment: I've done reinstall.  Wireless back. Painfully slow, as before.  Not sure where to start.  New output:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6741980/

Comment: I suggest a new question: "Slow wireless with rt2800pci" and include the wireless part of your paste. I will be glad to help.

Comment: Went to post new question, as suggested, but I can't even find that rt2800pci any more. Says I have RT3090.  I'm confused.  Should I just post it as you said anyway?

Comment: Isn't rt2800pci listed in lsmod?

Comment: Yes. I posted new question, as suggested.